# Averaging time series in aggregate in apply.daily() in R

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have several merged daily zoo timeseries (let's say the name of the merged set is 'test') that appear in the following format:

```
>test 


              TS1     TS2     TS3
2014-07-30    2.0     3.0     4.0
2014-07-31    2.5     3.0     4.5
2014-08-01    3.0     3.0     5.0
```

I am wanting to aggregate/manipulate the time series in several ways. However, the simplest averaging or suming is escaping me. I tried the following:

```
ts <- apply.daily(as.xts(test),mean)
```

which I had thought would give me the following output:

```
>ts

                  X    
    2014-07-30    3.0     
    2014-07-31    3.3     
    2014-08-01    3.7
```

However, it returns the same time series as before. I understand that this would be useful for `apply.weekly()` and `apply.monthly()`, both of which I plan to use, but how can I adapt all these functions to wrap TS1, TS2, and TS3 into an overall average on the same basis, whilst maintaining the zoo/xts formatting.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example showed, we can concatenate the rows and take the `mean`

```
apply.daily(as.xts(test), function(x) round(mean(c(x)),1))
#          [,1]
#2014-07-30  3.0
#2014-07-31  3.3
#2014-08-01  3.7
```

Note that using the OP's code on a daily dataset returns the input data as there is only a single observation for the criteria.  Suppose if the dataset is datetime class, then using `apply.daily` will return the `mean` for each single day, wrap it up with another `mean` to get the `mean` for each row, i.e.

```
test1 <- structure(list(TS1 = c(2, 2.5, 3, 2.2), TS2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3.2), 
TS3 = c(4, 4.5, 5, 4.4)), .Names = c("TS1", "TS2", "TS3"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2014-07-30 07:00:00", 
"2014-07-31 05:00:00", "2014-08-01 03:00:00", "2014-07-30 07:20:00"))

apply.daily(as.xts(test1), function(x) round(mean(mean(x)),1))
#                   [,1]
#2014-07-30 07:20:00  3.1
#2014-07-31 05:00:00  3.3
#2014-08-01 03:00:00  3.7
```

As we are using anonymous function, we don't need the two `mean`

```
 apply.daily(as.xts(test1), function(x) round(mean(x),1))
 #                     [,1]
 #2014-07-30 07:20:00  3.1
 #2014-07-31 05:00:00  3.3
 #2014-08-01 03:00:00  3.7
```

Checking the above results with OP's approach

```
apply.daily(as.xts(test1), mean)
#                   TS1 TS2 TS3
#2014-07-30 07:20:00 2.1 3.1 4.2
#2014-07-31 05:00:00 2.5 3.0 4.5
#2014-08-01 03:00:00 3.0 3.0 5.0

round(mean(c(2.1, 3.1, 4.2)), 1)
#[1] 3.1
round(mean(c(2.5, 3.0, 4.5)), 1)
#[1] 3.3
```